# Padding Issue when passing AES encrypted message from js Crypto to ESP8266

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, esp8266

This is my first foray into cybersecurity. I am attempting to put together a server with some security using the Crypto libraries on both server and client sides. Both supposedly use Pkcs7 padding. However the decrypted strings appear to differ in the padding. I was hoping someone could help me understand the issue.
This is intended for home monitoring devices that won't need MQTT.
The HTTPS server sends a random key and iv once at initial login to the client. The key is then used to encrypt the username and password, then sent back in the header under HTTP redirect. (The Esp8622 appears to be much too slow at serving pages in HTTPS). I have been successful at initially setting this up but the generated tailing padding bytes are different for the JavaScript compared to what the Esp8266 side generates.

### 1. Generated encryption/decryption:

```
ESP8266 SERVER SIDE:
------------------------------------------------------

13:08:17.110 -> enc (32 bytes) { 57 D4 80 55 2A AB D9 7E 28 6A CD FC 48 BA 56 7E E 89 31 E8 74 A4 CC 36 DA 64 C8 4B 69 EA A6 0 }
13:08:17.157 -> decrypted (32 bytes) { 75 73 65 72 6E 61 6D 65 20 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 3B 0 D D D D D D D D D D D D D }
13:08:17.157 -> Decrypted Packet HEX (32 bytes) { 75 73 65 72 6E 61 6D 65 20 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 3B 0 D D D D D D D D D D D D D }
13:08:17.157 -> Decrypted Packet (18 bytes):
13:08:17.157 -> username password;

2. From the client-sent header:
------------------------------------------------------
13:08:54.322 -> header: Cookie = 57D480552AABD97E286ACDFC48BA567E6F2DB84803A90BF90C8CC414DC0EF794
13:08:54.369 -> Found cookie: Number of headers= 3
13:08:54.369 -> 
13:08:54.369 -> new_message is :57D480552AABD97E286ACDFC48BA567E6F2DB84803A90BF90C8CC414DC0EF794
13:08:54.369 -> new_message length is :64
13:08:54.369 ->  { 57 D4 80 55 2A AB D9 7E 28 6A CD FC 48 BA 56 7E 6F 2D B8 48 3 A9 B F9 C 8C C4 14 DC E F7 94 }
13:08:54.369 -> 
13:08:54.369 -> On the receiving side:
13:08:54.369 -> enc (32 bytes) { 57 D4 80 55 2A AB D9 7E 28 6A CD FC 48 BA 56   7E 6F 2D B8 48 3 A9 B F9 C 8C C4 14 DC E F7 94 }
13:08:54.369 -> decrypted (32 bytes) { 75 73 65 72 6E 61 6D 65 20 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 3B E E E E E E E E E E E E E E }
13:08:54.416 -> Decrypted Packet HEX (32 bytes) { 75 73 65 72 6E 61 6D 65 20 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 3B E E E E E E E E E E E E E E }
13:08:54.416 -> Decrypted Packet (33 bytes):
13:08:54.416 -> username password;
```

### Esp8266 encryption/decryption code:

```
 AES aes(kEy, iv, AES::AES_MODE_128, AES::CIPHER_ENCRYPT);
 aes.process((uint8_t*)packet, encrypted, packetSize);

 AES aesDecryptor(kEy, iv, AES::AES_MODE_128, AES::CIPHER_DECRYPT);
 aesDecryptor.process((uint8_t*)enc , (uint8_t*)decrypted, decryptedSize);
```

### JAVASCRIPT result and code:

```
username password;
dXNlcm5hbWUgcGFzc3dvcmQ7
key: thisismykeyforit
iv: 0000000000000000
Cipher text: V9SAVSqr2X4oas38SLpWfm8tuEgDqQv5DIzEFNwO95Q=
57D480552AABD97E286ACDFC48BA567E6F2DB84803A90BF90C8CC414DC0EF794
757365726e616d652070617373776f72643b
username password;
```

```
<script>
var x; var x2; var use; var pas; var key; var iv; var message;

function myFunction() {
x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
x2 = document.getElementById("myText2").value;
sendCookie();
}
function sendCookie() {
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    message = this.responseText;
//  var comma = message.indexOf(",");
//  iv = message.substring(comma+1);
//  key = message.substring(0,comma);
    key= CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("7468697369736D796B6579666F726974");
    console.log(key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    iv=CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("0000000000000000");


    encrypt();
  }  
};
xhttp.open("POST", "response", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

```
    function encrypt() {
    use =  x;  pas = x2;
    message = use + " " + pas+";"; 

    var words = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message); // WordArray object
    console.log(words.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(words); 
    console.log(base64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

    console.log("key: " + key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); 
    console.log("iv: " + iv.toString()); 

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, {
    iv: iv });

    console.log("Cipher text: " + encrypted); 

    var Encrypt =base64toHEX(encrypted);
    var transitmessage =  encrypted.toString();
    console.log(Encrypt);

    document.cookie = Encrypt.toString(); // cookie for return to server  (Hex)
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(transitmessage, key, {
    iv: iv });

   console.log(decrypted.toString());
   console.log(hex_to_ascii(decrypted.toString())); 
   nudge();
   }
   function hex_to_ascii(str1)
   {
    var hex  = str1.toString();
    var str = '';
    for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) {
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16));
    }
    return str;
    }
    function nudge(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "nudge", true);
    request.send();
    console.log(this.responseText);
    }
```

```
Server (https://github.com/intrbiz/arduino-crypto) side encrypted to :
---------------------
57 D4 80 55 2A AB D9 7E 28 6A CD FC 48 BA 56 7E E 89 31 E8 74 A4 CC 36 DA 64 C8 4B 69 EA A6 0 
Decrypted:
---------------------
75 73 65 72 6E 61 6D 65 20 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 3B 0 D D D D D D D D D D D D D


Client (crypto.js) side encrypted to:
---------------------
57 D4 80 55 2A AB D9 7E 28 6A CD FC 48 BA 56 7E 6F 2D B8 48 03 A9 0B F9 0C 8C C4 14 DC 0E F7 94
Decrypted:
---------------------
75 73 65 72 6E 61 6D 65 20 70 61 73 73`enter code here` 77 6F 72 64 3B E E E E E E E E E E E E E E
```

```
Edit: Here's the code that keeps the terminating 0:
-----------------------------------------------------
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
int AES::calcSizeAndPad(int in_size)
{
    in_size++; // +1 for null terminater on input string
    int buf = round(in_size / AES_BLOCKSIZE) * AES_BLOCKSIZE;
    _size = (buf <= in_size) ? buf + AES_BLOCKSIZE : buf;
    _pad_size = _size - in_size;
    return _size;
}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Possibly the error is not in the padding. In the Esp8266-code it could also be that the plaintext contains an additional byte at the end with the value `0`. This could be the _terminating_ `0` of the plaintext-string, which is wrongly considered e.g. in the `packetSize`-parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the source code.

Comment: Found the code that includes the null terminator to the encryption, (see post edit) but I'm not sure what the fix would be. This would probably not be ideal but could a null terminator be added  to the string on the javascript side?

Comment: To reproduce the encryption of the Esp8266-code in the JavaScript-code, a `0`-byte must be appended in the JavaScript-code, e.g. with `var message = use + " " + pas + ";" + "\0";`.

Comment: Yes that does it. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.